# Connect Blackberry menuitem to onscreen buttons

Tags: blackberry, button, screen, menuitem

I have requirement for having onscreen navigation buttons along with menu items on blackberry. I need to generate menu item commands as onscreen buttons. Is there a way to generate onscreen menu item buttons in Blackberry? i.e On each screen of my application the menu items should be populated as onscreen buttons both having same functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you're trying to do is write one function then have both the button and the menu item use the same function.

For example:

```
function doSomething() {
   // Your Code Here
}

// In the function building your screen
MenuItem somethingMi = new MenuItem() {
  private MenuItem() { super("Do Something",100001, 5); }

  public void run() { doSomething() };
}

Button somethingBtn = new ButtonField("Do Something");
somethingBtn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context){
    doSomething();
  }
}

addMenuItem(somethingMI);
add(somethingBtn);
```

Comment: Thanks guys,I am doing it the way as you've said. But I was expecting some way to automatically populate menu items as  on screen buttons as My applications involves many dynamically created screens. Looks like BB is not in favor of on screen buttons.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not following what you're asking for. Why would I want a menu item to show up on screen as a button if I'm carefully designing my GUI? E Everything after `// In the function` can be broken apart and wrapped in if statements, making it easier to do in a more dynamic way. By the way you ask your question, you must have seen something else do this before, can you give me an example?